# Vue js "store is not defined" in router.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I want to perform a redirect, but before the redirect happens i want to perform a action using store.dispatch. Error is "store is not defined" in the console.

I have tried putting the whole line of code in a variable and check if true and if null, the error dissapears but the actions never gets called, and the debugger shows vue is jumping over the if-statement.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from './store/index'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Settings from './views/Settings.vue'


Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/myPath',
            name: 'myPathName',
            component: {},
            beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
                //STORE is not defined
                store.dispatch("path/MY_ACTION");
                    next({
                        name: "destinationPath", 
                    })
            }
        }
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
MY STORE
// STORE -> MODULES -> CONFIGURATION -> INDEX
import windowsModule from "../windows/index"
import mainDoorModule from "../maindoor/index"
import doorLeavesModule from "../doorleaves/index"
import doorModule from "../door/index"
import actions from "./actions"
import mutations from "./mutations"

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    modules: {
        windows: windowsModule,
        mainDoor: mainDoorModule,
        doorLeaves: doorLeavesModule,
        door: doorModule
    },
    state: {
        configurationId: 0,
        savedConfigurationsViewModel: [],
        errors: {},
        configurationsToSend: []
    },
    mutations,
    actions
}

//THE ACTION I AM TRYING TO REACH INSIDE ACTIONS
// STORE -> MODULES -> CONFIGURATION -> ACTIONS 

GET_DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION({ commit }) {
    commit('SET_CONFIGURATION', {
        //DATA
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `this.$store.dispatch`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Still undefined.

Comment: Update your code with a larger fragment, because if it is not a component but a main module, it may mean that you have installed it incorrectly.

Comment: show your `store`

Comment: @Gander so i've added to show some imports, but i dont really know what would make sense to show. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I think you're not export store correctly.

Comment: @Daniyal Lukmanov i updated the code snippet, was that what you were asking for?

Comment: what is this `// STORE -> MODULES -> CONFIGURATION -> INDEX`?

Comment: Daniyal Lukmanov index.js is the state where we store some data, what i was trying to comment was the path

Comment: Does it mean that your `store` is actually in `store/modules/configuration/index.js`?

Comment: Daniyal Lukmanov that is were we store some particular data, we have one index (store) for every module, we also have a index located in the store folder that stores other data

Comment: then show your `store/index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it resolved. It was a Chrome bug saying that store is undefined, it's in webpack. Store was defined. 
The problem was the mismatch between actions and mutations sending payloads that did not match types.

Thanks for all the answers, i appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install it in the main component. Then you refer to this through `this.$store`. Read the Vuex documentation.

```js
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {},
  mutations: {},
  getters: {}
})
```

```js
import store from './store/index'

new Vue({
  store, // <- here
  el: '#app'
})
```